# Server 2008 T/S program reinstalls every time it starts for different users

Tags: vb6, windows-installer, terminal-services

Our application which runs fine on previous versions of TS have a new "issue" when running on TS on Server 2008 R2.

A user logs in and starts the application.  They're shown an installation dialog. If it's a new install/re-install you might expect this while the registry gets updated with new settings and "stuff" from the new installation.

After the user logs in, they can log out and back in with no issues.  AS LONG AS.. No one else has started the program in the interim. AS soon as another user connects and starts the program (they get the installation dialogs as well..) the first user will now have to go thru the installation dialogs again..

The application is bastardized in VB6, with no real plans for "upgrade", although "re-write" has been bantered about a bit.. I'm currently looking for Registry "issues" for the Win2008 vs. Win2000 handling of UAC & registry..

Any ideas for things that are gonna bite me in my quest for VB6 perfection?  :-) !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 : Look at event viewer to get the Component ID causing the resilency trigger

Step 2 : Examine the MSI in Orca to know what the keyfile of that component is

Step 3: Mitigate ( depends a lot on what you find in step 2 )

Just please don't do crazy things that I've seen people do like disable the windows installer service or use MSIZap to make MSI 'forget' about the app.  ( Ooops, suppose I shouldn't have told you that. JK )

Comment: I have found in the event viewer it seems the app (or Windows) is looking for instmsiw.exe in the user's temp folder & not finding it, which seems to be causing Win Installer to start up(it's the next event reported..).. I'm looking thru the installer package now..

Comment: As a quick fix you might be able to edit the MSI in Orca to remove that component and then reinstall it on the T/S using msiexec /i foo.msi REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus /qb    This should make MSI forget about that component and stop trying to repair it.  On a larger basis,  I understand that you have irate users but the problem occurred a long time ago and wasn't caught in your QA.  Nothing I can do about that.   You disable msiserver service for now while you work the issue out in DEV/QA and then renable it when it's time to promote the new installer.

Comment: Thanks man,  Very helpful answers. I'm currently chasing MS's version of the fix for VB6 app installation on UAC type machines.. Making sure nothing is installed to the wrong folders, (of which there are a few..), and making sure all the re-distributables are up to date with MS's latest official "blessing" on them..  Then I'm gonna see where the app stands.. I'll post more back later, cause so far, as best I can tell, this is the first intelligent discussion about this issue..

Comment: OK, found that the program is looking for INSTMSIW in the users temp folder, and the OS was then complaining that is wasn't there when in fact it was there. I also found the packager was using an ancient INSTMSIW.exe file. I went to MS's site to get the latest of the instmisw (and a few other files located in the same temp directory..) Also I found they are "suggesting" replacement of a number of other COM files from the VB Installation.  I updated these files as well.  Repackaged the program, and tested with 100% success.  Thanks again @ChristopherPainter

Comment: Any other VB6 Developers out there with the same issue, check the following at Microsoft..  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788229.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708